# Efficiently solving this recurrence relation. [ Better than O(N^2) ]

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

I've a recurrence relation which goes something like this:

> E( i, j ) = A[ i ] + A[ j ] + E( i+1, j-1 ) + E( i+2, j ) + E( i, j-2 ) ;  if i  !=  j
>
> E( i, j ) = A[ i ] ; if( i == j )
> E( i, j ) = 0 ; if i < 0 or j < 0 
> A[ i ] 1 <= i <= N; is simple integer array.

I want to solve for E(1, N) in time complexity better than O(N^2). I was wondering if we could find some closed form formula for this recurrence or maybe a clever method of computing the value of E(1, N)?

Any hints are welcome,
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The actual problem is like this:

1. We have an array A[], and 2 Players take turns to play this game.
2. A player can pick the leftmost or rightmost number with probability 0.5 and adds it to his score(if there's single element left in array he will simply pick that number and the game ends).
3. Question is to find the expected score that Player1 will achieve.

Comment: I doubt it. You might be able to find a different way of solving the underlying problem though, so I think you should post that.

Comment: Okay, I'll post the problem in a minute but suppose if we have an efficient alternate way to solve the underlying problem, shouldn't that approach kind of reflect here as in- solving this recurrence more efficiently? or maybe not necessarily!

Comment: Problem looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758652.

Comment: Nabb: Yes, its' same problem but apparently theres' a better approach than O(N^2). I've already tried DP with memoization.

Comment: @srbh.kmr What makes you think it can be done in less than O(n^2) ?

Comment: Well, for one- the online judge gives me a 'time limit exceeded' for the best optimized code I wrote and second- I tried building the DP table in a worksheet and the way values add up to the corner cell seems tractable enough to 'bring down' the O(N^2) computation but not quite. so, I was wondering if its' possible to find some closed form exression for the same.

Comment: Problem looks like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873730/sum-all-possible-values-a-player-can-have-in-a-two-player-game

Answer (score 3):

About your recurrence relation:

It appears somewhat difficult because the write-up suggests, that for E(1,N) we need E(2,..) and E(3,..), each of which in turn requires other entries with yet higher "i", etcetera.

Now, rearrange the terms such that we have the E-term with the highest "i" isolated (a good idea in general with recurrence relations is to have a look at different arrangements to isolate a particular index - the highest, the lowest, the middle one, ...):

E(i+2,j) = E(i,j) - E(i,j-2) - E(i+1,j-1) - A(i) - A(j)

Then, shift all i down by 2 (simply rewriting the formula)

E(i,j) = E(i-2,j) - E(i-2,j-2) - E(i-1,j-1) - A(i-2) - A(j).

Then, for {i=1, j=N}, which is what you're looking for, we get:

E(1,N) = E(-1,N) - E(-1,N-2) - E(0,N-1) - A(-1) - A(N) = -A(N), because all other terms are zero.

(I assume, of course, that E(i,j) and A(i) are zero for i=0 / j=0; your specification was presumably incomplete when you specified the zero-values only for NEGATIVE indices, but not for the zero-indices).

Then, about your (edited) description of the underlying case - two players taking in turn from A, arbitrarily from left or right, until A is exhausted:

From the previous result, I don't think it's likely that your recurrence relation describes the underlying game, given the outcome -A(N)... Therefore, leave that recurrence relation aside (it's solved anyway for i=1). and have a look at the game itself for what relations we may derive.

[CONTINUED AFTER EDIT]

So far, I haven't come up with something that I can cast in a closed form, i.e. something that is faster than processing some kind of recurrence relations. For the moment, therefore, let's write down how we might describe the game in a way that lends itself to calculation.

Define the following quantities:

Let X(i,k) be the probability that item #i (in array A) still exists (i.e. has not yet been taken by any player) at the end of turn #k (counting turns from both players). Of course, k runs in our game from 1 to N, and so does i. For verification purposes we may note, that X(i,N) must be zero for all i: at the end of the game all elements have been taken.

In case we may need (in formula-evaluations) any values of X(i,k) outside the "normal" range, we assess:

```
X(i,k)=1 for {1<=i<=N; k=0}: initially all elements in A are still there.
X(i,k)=0 whenever i<1 or i>N: no elements ever exist outside the (original) range of A.
```

Next, let T(i,k) be the probability that element #i is taken (by any player) at turn #k exactly.
That must be 0.5 * the probability that it is the leftmost element (currently), which is equivalent to saying that element #(i-1) does NOT exist at the end of the PREVIOUS turn, plus 0.5 * the probability that it is the rightmost element (currently), which in turn amounts to saying that element #(i+1) does not exist at the end of the previous turn, while all of that must be multiplied by the probability that element #i itself exists in the first place:

```
T(i,k) = X(i,k-1) * ( (1-X(i-1,k-1)) + (1-X(i+1,k-1)) ) / 2
```

The probability X(i,k) that element #i still exists after turn #k is the probability that it existed at the end of the previous turn, minus the probability that it is taken at turn #k:

```
X(i,k) = X(i,k-1) - T(i,k)
```

The probability that element #i winds up with player#1 is the summation over all turns k of T(i,k), but only counting HIS turns. Let's denote that quantity by P(i,1), where 1 stands for player #1.

```
P(i,1) = sum{ k=1,3,...: T(i,k) }
```

Likewise, for player #2:

```
P(i,2) = sum{ k=2,4,...: T(i,k) }
```

The expected score of player #1 is then the sum S(1):

```
S(1) = sum( i=1..N: P(i,1)*A(i) }, and likewise for player #2: S(2) = sum( i=1..N: P(i,2)*A(i) }
```

Looking at the above formula's I don't see a way to avoid an O(N2) method as regards time. Memory-usage can be O(N) as we may keep running totals and discard older 'element-wise'-data that won't be needed anymore. Given that - assuming you're not processing arrays A that are excessively long - the players wouldn't survive! - the O(n2) time-performance shouldn't be such an issue in practice.

```
int N  = sizeof(A);

// note on the code below: we'll use i as an integer running over the elements in A, and k running over the turns that players make.
// while in human parlance we would have them (both) run from 1 to N, the zero-based arrays of C++ make it more convenient to let them 
// run from 0 to N-1.

// initialize the running totals P(i), the accumulated (over turns) probabilities that element #i winds up with player #1.
// if we ever need the same for player #2, it's values are of course 1-P (that is: at the end of the game).
double* P = new double[N];
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  P[i] = 0; // before we start, there's little chance that player #1 has already taken any element.
}
// initialize the existence-array for the elements.
int* X = new int[N];
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  X[i] = 1; // initially all elements exist, i.e. have not yet been taken by any player.
}
// declare an array for processing the probabilities that elements are taken at a particular turn.
double* T = new double[N];

// iterate over the turns.
for (int k=0; k<N; k++)
{
  // for each element, calculate the probability that it is taken NOW.
  // the current values of X - the existence array - refer to the (end of the) previous turn.
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
    // note: take care of the boundaries i=0 and i=N-1.
    if (i == 0)
    {
      T[i] = X[i] * ( 2 - X[i+1] ) / 2;
    }
    else if (i == N-1)
    {
      T[i] = X[i] * ( 2 - X[i-1] ) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
      T[i] = X[i] * ( 2 - X[i-1] - X[i+1] ) / 2;
    }
  } // element i
  // with the take-probabilities for this turn in place, update P - only at odd turns (i.e. k=even): P is for player #1 only.
  if (k % 2 == 0)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
      P[i] += T[i];
    }
  }
  // finally - in this turn - update the existence array.
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
    X[i] -= T[i];
  }

} // turn k

// result: calculate the expected score for player #1.
double score = 0;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  score += P[i] * A[i];
}
```

--

Comment: Bert: Thanks for your thorough analysis. I think what broke that recurrence is the shifting of 'i down by 2' because the recurrence was defined in a bottom up manner and shifting of i to i-2 was an attempt to define some values in terms of already unknown values. I think rest of your analysis combined, somewhat resembles the recurrence I had: `E(i, j) = 0.5 * A[i] + 0.5 * A[j] + 0.5 * E(i+1, j-1) + 0.25 * E(i+2, j) + 0.25 * E(i, j-2).`  where, `E(i, j)` is expected score that player1 can achieve with subarray `A[i, j]`, which can be implemented with  `O(N^2)` time complexity and `O(N)` space.

Comment: Well, glad I could help you some. Bear in mind that you may DEVISE a recurrence relation in a bottom-up manner, but it is always DEFINED in all directions. This implies that you'll always have to consider the boundaries for the relevant indices and consequently may need to supply additional definitions to make sure that the recurrence relation is fully valid.

Answer (score -1):

Since probabilities are equal, this is just a counting problem.

Can you figure out that chances of picking A[j] on the k^th turn?

Comment: I don't see any evidence that this is an answer.

Comment: @david: Perhaps if you tried reading the question again? It clearly says, any hints welcome...

Comment: Even so. What hint(s) are you giving?

Comment: @david: What I was hinting was exactly what I wrote: Try computing that chances that A[j] gets picked on the k^th turn. I believe we can even give a closed form formula for this. In fact, this seems to be the missing step in the other answer.

Comment: That comment sounds better than your answer. I am just trying to help you. Accepting it or not is up to you.

Comment: @david: I understand. I hope you understand I am trying to help you figure out that if someone asks for a hint, a two liner can be as good as a verbose answer. I am trying to get OP (and any other reader) to think about this. If people choose not to think, it is upto them. Of course, OP asks for a hint and completely ignores this, so you are probably right, but I suppose the downvote could also have been a factor in people ignoring this answer (and frankly, I don't care if people downvote and choose to ignore).